# Awk How can I sum rows in groups of 40

Tags: awk

I have a csv file here with 3 fields and on the third field I would like to group rows into not more than 25.

Given:
"CW-03";(PE.502);24
"CW-04";(PE.501);25
"CW-05";(PE.518,PE.518-1);2
"CW-06";(PE.517);1
"CW-07";(PE.516);3
"CW-08";(PE.515);1
"CW-09";(PE.514);1
"CW-10";(PE.513,PE.513-1);23
"CW-11";(PE.512);8
"CW-12";(PE.511);1
"CW-13";(PE.510);3
"CW-14";(PE.509);3
"CW-15";(PE.508,PE.508-1);17
"CW-16";(PE.507);1
"CW-17";(PE.506);1
"CW-18";(PE.505);1
"CW-19";(PE.521,PE.569);2
"CW-20";(PE.520,PE.568);17
"CW-21";(PE.519,PE.567);17
"CW-22";(PE.526,PE.526-1,PE.574,PE.574-1);4
"CW-23";(PE.525,PE.573);2
"CW-24";(PE.524,PE.572);2
"CW-25";(PE.523,PE.571);3
"CW-26";(PE.522,PE.522-1,PE.570,PE.570-1);19

Desired output:
"CW-03";(PE.502);**24**
"CW-04";(PE.501);**25**
"CW-05";**(PE.518,PE.518-1,PE.517,PE.516,PE.515,PE.514);8**
"CW-10";(PE.513,PE.513-1);**23**
"CW-11";**(PE.509,PE.510,PE.511,PE.512);15**

Can you help me?

Comment: It may be early morning over here but I really don't understand how you come to that desired output. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=";" }
     f{ if(c+$3 > 25) { gsub(/\),\(/,",",r); print r,c; f=c=0 } else { c+=$3; r=r","$2 } }
     !f && c<25{ f=1; c=$3; r=$1 FS $2 }
     END{ if(c) gsub(/\),\(/,",",r); print r,c }' file
```

The output:

```
"CW-03";(PE.502);24
"CW-04";(PE.501);25
"CW-05";(PE.518,PE.518-1,PE.517,PE.516,PE.515,PE.514);8
"CW-10";(PE.513,PE.513-1);23
"CW-11";(PE.512,PE.511,PE.510,PE.509);15
"CW-15";(PE.508,PE.508-1,PE.507,PE.506,PE.505,PE.521,PE.569);22
"CW-20";(PE.520,PE.568);17
"CW-21";(PE.519,PE.567,PE.526,PE.526-1,PE.574,PE.574-1,PE.525,PE.573,PE.524,PE.572);25
"CW-25";(PE.523,PE.571,PE.522,PE.522-1,PE.570,PE.570-1);22
```

Comment: Yes. I tried it and do accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat awk-script
function print_line(str1,str2,sum)
{
  print str1 OFS "(" str2 ")" OFS sum  # print the format as your request
}
NR==1 {
  str1=$1                              
  str2=$3                              # Use the str2 to store the combined output for $3
  sum=$5                               # Use sum to store the sum of $5
  next
}
{
  sum+=$5
  if (sum>25){                         # If sum is greater than 25
    print_line(str1,str2,sum-$5)       # print the line in the desired format
    str1=$1                            # and reset the str1 to $1
    str2=""                            # str2 to ""
    sum=$5                             # sum to $5
  }
  str2=(str2?str2",":str2"")$3         # update the str2 based on if str2 is ""
}
END {
  print_line(str1,str2,sum)            # flush the final result
}
```

Adopt the awk-script using following command,

```
$ awk -F'[();]' -v OFS=';' -f awk-script file
"CW-03";(PE.502);24
"CW-04";(PE.501);25
"CW-05";(PE.518,PE.518-1,PE.517,PE.516,PE.515,PE.514);8
"CW-10";(PE.513,PE.513-1);23
"CW-11";(PE.512,PE.511,PE.510,PE.509);15
"CW-15";(PE.508,PE.508-1,PE.507,PE.506,PE.505,PE.521,PE.569);22
"CW-20";(PE.520,PE.568);17
"CW-21";(PE.519,PE.567,PE.526,PE.526-1,PE.574,PE.574-1,PE.525,PE.573,PE.524,PE.572);25
"CW-25";(PE.523,PE.571,PE.522,PE.522-1,PE.570,PE.570-1);22
```